# Does the Beast Conclave ranger's animal companion get a boost when you get it at 3rd level?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, animal-companions

In the [Ranger Unearthed Arcana](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/UA_RevisedRanger.pdf), I have chosen the Beast Conclave at level 3.

Does my animal companion start with the stats from the monster manual or does it immediately gain my +2 proficiency bonus to its armor class? Maybe some extra HP?

I chose a Giant Weasel as my first companion, but it seems a little weak.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### It gets the benefits immediately

You get the Companion's Bond feature at 3rd level, at the same time as you gain the Animal Companion feature.

The Companion's Bond feature says:

> In addition to the areas where it 
>   normally    uses    its proficiency bonus,  an  animal
>   companion   also    adds    its proficiency bonus to    its 
>   AC  and to  its damage  rolls.

This applies from 3rd level and onwards, so it gets a +2 to its attack rolls, ability and skill checks, saves, AC and damage, and loses Multiattack if it had it.

Once you reach 4th level, and every level beyond that, it gets an extra hit die:

> For    each    level   you gain    after   3rd,    your    animal
>   companion   gains   an  additional  hit die and 
>   increases   its hit points accordingly.

This means that your giant weasel's stats look like this:

#### Giant Weasel

Medium beast, unaligned

**Armor Class** 15 (13 +2 proficiency)

**Hit Points** 9 (2d8)

**Speed** 40 ft.

**Ability Scores**
(+2 proficiency to all saves)
**STR** 11 (+0)
**DEX** 16 (+3)
**CON** 10 (+0)
**INT** 4 (-3)
**WIS** 12 (+1)
**CHA** 5 (-3)

**Skills** Perception +5, Stealth +7

**Senses** darkvision 60 ft., passive Perception 13

**Languages** —

**Challenge** 1/8 (25 XP)

**Keen Hearing and Smell**: The weasel has advantage on Wisdom (Perception) checks that rely on hearing or smell.

**Actions**

**Bite**: *Melee Weapon Attack*: +5 to hit (+3 +2 proficiency), reach 5 ft., one target. Hit: 7 (1d4 + 3 + 2 proficiency) piercing damage.

Comment: You need to revise the attack roll as you've added in the proficiency bonus twice. The base animal includes a proficiency bonus in it's attack roll, there's no reason to add it again.

Comment: @Pyrotechnical Yes, we replace the beast's prof bonus with character's prof bonus.  I fixed it.

Comment: You've given the G. Weasel 2 prof bonuses in perception & stealth: its own bonus AND the PC's bonus. It should only get the PC's. The monster stat block lists its skills as perception and stealth, so it gets a +2 bonus added to its abil bonus, hence the MM stat block shows it with percep +3 (+1 wis bonus & +2 prof bonus), and stealth +5 (+3 dex bonus & +2 prof). PHB p93: "Add your [prof] bonus to the beasts's AC, attack rolls, and damage rolls, as well as to any saving throws and skills it is [prof] in." See also UA Revised Ranger: "Your companion uses your [prof] bonus rather than its own."

Answer (score 2):

From UA:RevisedRanger

> At the end of the 8 hours, your animal companion appears and gains all
>   the benefits of your Companion’s Bond ability.

This is true even the first time you create a companion. (Note that you do not gain the companion as a feature, but the ability to create one.) The bonus to AC and most other changes compared to the base beast are parts of Companion’s Bond and are thus applied.

Comment: Yes I did mannage to lure it with some "fine herbs"

Answer (score 2):

**The animal companion does get a boost when you obtain it.**

Usually proficiency bonus is applied to the following stats:

- Skills
- Attack Bonus
- Saving throws

These bonuses are already included in the monster stat block. However, for an animal companion, the stats improved by a proficiency bonus are described as:

> your companion’s proficiency bonus (...)    is  applied to  the following   areas:  Armor   Class, skills,  saving  throws, attack  bonus,  and damage  rolls.

This adds AC and damage to the list of stats affected by proficiency which is explicitly clarified:

> In    addition    to  the areas   where   it   normally   uses    its proficiency bonus,  an  animal   companion  also    adds    its proficiency bonus to    its  AC and to  its damage  rolls.

This means that the stats for your initial companion are calculated as follows:

1. Get all the stats for the animal companion from the stat block.
2. Add +2 to AC and damage rolls for the beast's attacks
3. Check for any saving throw proficiencies (any saving throws explicitly stated in the monster stat block). Add +2 to all the unlisted saving throw proficiencies (which is the normal stat modifier +2)
4. Choose 2 skills that are not explicitly listed in the stat block. Your companion becomes proficient in them, (they now use the base stat modifier asociated with the skill +2)

Note that this assumes no multiclassing:

> When  you gain    your    animal  companion   at  3rd level,  its 
>   proficiency bonus   matches yours   at  +2.

When multiclassing it is probably easier to first calculate all the stats as though your proficiency was +2, then add the extra proficiency bonus to all aplicable areas